# How can I read the Rust documentation offline?

Tags: rust

I use the default installation of Rust and want to read the doc following this [tutorial](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/second-edition/ch01-01-installation.html#local-documentation):

```
$ rustup doc
```

But the above command outputs the following error:
[image]

There is indeed no `html` directory:

```
$ ls /home/xiaonan/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/share/doc/rust/
COPYRIGHT  LICENSE-APACHE  LICENSE-MIT  README.md
```

How can I read the Rust documentation offline?

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, could you add the output of `rustup component list` to your question?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need to add the `rust-docs` component, like this:

```
rustup component add rust-docs
```

This will add the component if it's not installed already and will keep it up to date, whenever you update the toolchain it belongs to.

Comment: Maybe also add how to open the docs from another rust stable toolchain.

Comment: Also you can open rust book with `rustup doc --book`